# OpenXml replace bookmark text without lossing styles

Tags: .net, openxml

Is it possible to change a bookmark text without deleting the style?
If not, is it possible to obtain the style of the bookmark, copy and insert the style in the new text?

My code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(finalPath, true))
        {

            foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>())
            {
                if (bookmarkStart.Name.Equals("Title"))
                {
                    OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();

                    while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
                    {
                        OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
                        elem.Remove();
                        elem = nextElem;
                    }

                    bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(new Run(new Text("LOREM IPTSUM")), bookmarkStart);
                }
            }
        }
```